# How to skip blank lines with read_fwf in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use [`pandas.read_fwf()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) function in Python pandas 0.19.2 to read a file `fwf.txt` that has the following content:

```
# Column1 Column2
      123     abc

      456     def

#
#
```

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = "fwf.txt"
widths = [len("# Column1"), len(" Column2")]
names = ["Column1", "Column2"]
data = pd.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer=file_path, widths=widths, 
                   names=names, skip_blank_lines=True, comment="#")
```

The printed dataframe is like this:

```
    Column1 Column2
0   123.0   abc
1   NaN     NaN
2   456.0   def
3   NaN     NaN
```

It looks like the `skip_blank_lines=True` argument is ignored, as the dataframe contains NaN's.

What should be the valid combination of `pandas.read_fwf()` arguments that would ensure the skipping of blank lines?

Comment: Try taking out the `comment` argument, it might be overriding the `skip_blank_lines`

Comment: @rassar That was my thought too, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Mitch Hmm...in the docs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) it says `skip_blank_lines` defaluts to `True`...maybe take that one out?

Comment: @rassar That won't help.. `True is True` - OP is just being explicit :)

Comment: Not sure how blank lines are defined for pandas. Perhaps it only filters `\n` but not other whitespace?.  One post-parsing option would be to drop `NaN` rows with `data.dropna(how="all", inplace=True) `

Comment: it looks like a Pandas bug to me...

Comment: [Duplicate ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605909/blank-lines-skip-true-fails-with-read-fwf)

Comment: @B. M., that is a question on a similar function in R

Comment: Yes it seems to be a bug that `read_fwf` is disregarding `skip_blank_lines`. You can get a message when NA values are inferred by enabling `verbose=True`. You could report this bug as a [pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). Also you can disable NAs being inferred on blank lines with `na_filter = None`

Answer (score 3):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
file_path = "fwf.txt"
widths = [len("# Column1 "), len("Column2")]
names = ["Column1", "Column2"]

class FileLike(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
    def readline(self):
        return next(self.iterable)

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if line.strip())
    data = pd.read_fwf(FileLike(lines), widths=widths, names=names, 
                       comment='#')
    print(data)
```

prints

```
   Column1 Column2
0      123     abc
1      456     def
```

---

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if line.strip())
```

defines a generator expression (i.e. an iterable) which yields
lines from the file with blank lines removed.

The `pd.read_fwf` function can accept `TextIOBase` objects.  You can subclass
`TextIOBase` so that its `readline` method returns lines from an iterable:

```
class FileLike(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
    def readline(self):
        return next(self.iterable)
```

Putting these two together gives you a way to manipulate/modify lines of a file
before passing them to `pd.read_fwf`.